# Django creating model instances without keyword arguments

Tags: python, django, arguments, instance, models

In Django, if you want to create a model you can do it as follows:

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    a = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    b = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    c = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    d = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    e = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    f = models.CharField(max_length=60)
```

Now if you want to create an instance in the shell, you have to do:

```
> abcdef = SomeModel(a="stuff", b="stuff", c="stuff", d="stuff", e="stuff", f="stuff")
```

This gets really annoying if you have to keep creating model instances with long property names. Is there a way to simply send the arguments like you would with a normal Python object (as in without having to name the variables and just send the variables in order) ?

Like this:

```
> abcdef = SomeModel("stuff", "stuff", "stuff", "stuff", "stuff", "stuff")
```

As you would with a standard Python class in the **init** function.

Thanks :)

Here is my actual Python model:

```
class School(models.Model):
    urn = models.CharField(max_length=6)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    house = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    street = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    county = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    postcode = models.CharField(max_length=8)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(
            'URN: ' + self.urn + ', ' +
            'Name: ' + self.name + ', ' +
            'House: ' + self.house + ', ' +
            'Street: ' + self.street + ', ' +
            'County: ' + self.county + ', ' +
            'Postcode: ' + self.postcode + ', '
            )
```

Comment: Did you try it? A Django model *is* a normal Python object.

Comment: Yeah I tried it. The first argument is the primary key, and results in an error :/ I know it can be manipulated the normal way, but what I essentially want to change is the __init__ function.

Comment: Ah, good point. Well, how about just passing `None` as the first argument? Then the pk will stay as None, and be set as normal on save.

Comment: The PK was set normally. But whenever I try to display the object is says [Bad Unicode data] (in the __unicode__ representation).

Comment: Well that sounds like a different problem. Perhaps you should post the `__unicode__` method.

Comment: Added my full model :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the following code:

```
obj = SomeModel(None, "a_stuff", "b_stuff", "c_stuff", "d_stuff", "e_stuff", "f_stuff")
obj.save()
```

Hope these helps.

Comment: Yes. But whenever I try to display the object, it gives [Bad Unicode Data] error in the display as opposed to my     __unicode__ function. I've added my model in the question :)

Comment: @Pictraz i think you have a mistake inside `__unicode__` method. Try to remove `str` wrapper.

Comment: Ah I think I see it. Does str() not return a unicode string?

Comment: @Pictraz, not at all :)

Answer (score 0):

you can create instance by doing

```
abcdef = SomeModel()
```

Since instantiating doesnot touch the database, you can assign values later and then do `.save()`.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question haha. What I don't know is how to send the arguments as:

    > abcdef = SomeModel("stuff", "stuff", "stuff", "stuff", "stuff", "stuff")